# No return of "yield return WWW" method in the second run

Tags: debugging, web, return, unity-game-engine, yield

I'm tracking the following method in Unity3D environment:
 (called through StartCoroutine)

```
private IEnumerator post(string s) {
    Debug.Log("Posting to Server: " + s);

    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("data", s);   

    WWW yaPoster = new WWW(YMCA_URL,form);  

        Debug.log("11111");     
        yield return yaPoster;  
        Debug.log("22222");

        if(yaPoster.error != null) {  
            Debug.Log(yaPoster.error);
        }  
        else {  
            Debug.Log(yaPoster.text);
        }

    yaPoster = null;    
}
```

It works well for every first time (saw yaPoster.text from log console), but never can see the "11111" or "22222" in the followed calls.

(Not) surprisingly, things run well on my iPod device with the built iOS Xcode project.

Any specific settings I should apply for my Unity3D environment so that I don't need to debug my code only with the real device?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it should work just fine!

A wild guess: Turn off **Collapse** in the Console? Could be that you're just not seeing it the second time because identical messages are not being shown if **Collapse** is enabled

If you want to keep Collapse enabled, change your Debug.Logs to include Time.time like this:

```
Debug.Log(Time.time + ": " + "11111"); //adding some uniqueness to keep it from collapsing
```

(Sorry, don't have enough rep to post this as a comment)